# How to display only a exact region (tiles for exact region) with maptalks?

Tags: javascript, maps, openstreetmap

I need to show only one region on the map. For example Alaska or New-York city. How I can do this by using Maptalks or at least OpenStreetMap?

Comment: Which library? Usually you achieve this by restricting the view to a specific bounding box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display only exact region on map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55572273/how-to-display-only-exact-region-on-map)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is relevant to maptalks library.

1. Get boundaries via nominatim.openstreetmap.org API in a geojson
   format.
2. Set a multipolygon mask to a baselayer