# How to display only exact region on any open-source map (like maptalks)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, openstreetmap

I need to show only one region on the map. For example Alaska or New-York city.

Comment: Could you show some code ?

Comment: Which library? Usually you achieve this by restricting the view to a specific bounding box.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapRestriction - do not follow the answers you have received so far, they are either wrong, incomplete or do not make use of the adequate interface provided by the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is relevant to many js libraries.
1. Get boundaries via nominatim.openstreetmap.org API in a geojson format.
2. Set polygon/multipolygon mask on a [base]layer

Answer (score -1):

You could find you'r area boundary and set map to limit panning.
look at sample below:

```
var allowedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
 new google.maps.LatLng(70.33956792419954, 178.01171875), 
 new google.maps.LatLng(83.86483689701898, -88.033203125)
);
var lastValidCenter = map.getCenter();

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
   if (allowedBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) {
       // still within valid bounds, so save the last valid position
       lastValidCenter = map.getCenter();
       return; 
   }

   // not valid anymore => return to last valid position
   map.panTo(lastValidCenter);
});
```

Also you can use this link: https://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/9d4jy4ye/